# Is this implementation of the one time pad semanticly secure?

Tags: security, math, cryptography, encryption

I have been taking a cryptography class( https://class.coursera.org/crypto-009 ), and we were discussing the one time pad cipher(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad).

The teacher was saying that this cipher is not practical because they keys would have to be worked out in advance over a secure means of communication and are as long as the data string.

But what if instead of having the key be a long binary number that was worked out ahead of time, every time we needed a new key we would use the xor of two repeating decimals, and every time we needed to send a message, we used as many digits from the xor of the two repeating decimals as we need, and then burn the digits we used.

Both parties would have two repeating decimals for them self, and two for the other person so that they would be able to decipher the messages they receive.

```
#We will burn all of the bits we use, plus a certain number of extra bits on the end 
#of each repeating decimal each time we use it.
#The sender will calculate this number of extra bits to burn, and then included
#it as a header or tag in the contents of the message
randIntA = random int

#Alternately, it could be calculated based off of the length or contents of the message 
randIntB = random int

d1 = repeating decimal

d2 = repeating decimal != d1

R = d1 xor d2 

m1 = binary(text)

#Note: I made this notation in a python style, but if this were python,
#I would have said R[:len(m1)+2]
E = (m1 , R[:len(m1)])==>C

C = m1 xor R[:len(m1)]

#We burn the number of bits that we used plus a certain number(randintA and randintB respectivly) of extra bits on the end of each repeating decimal

d1=d1[len(m1)+randlen:]

d2=d2[len(m1)+randlen:]
```

TLDR reversion:Can you make an OTP key using a pair of repeating decimals.

Comment: That is **not** in any real sense a one time pad.

Comment: I apologize if I messed up some of the notation.The basic idea was just "Can you make an OTP key using a pair of repeating decimals."

Comment: As long as the decimals repeat *randomly*, and are only written down twice (or there is a secure way to transmit them between receiver and sender). You have shown none of the preceding.

Comment: This is better suited for http://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with using repeating decimals this way is that if you XOR them, they still repeat. If one number has a repeating sequence of N bits and the other has a repeating sequence of M bits, then their XOR will repeat <= LCM(M, N) <= M*N bits, and you'll start leaking information after on the order of M+N bits. This is essentially useless.

There are ways to apply the technique of a 1-time pad with a shorter key length; these are [stream ciphers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_cipher). They expand a short key into a very long, random-seeming stream of bits in a way designed to make it very difficult for an attacker to determine useful information about the key or the rest of the stream, given part of the stream. They do not achieve the unbreakability of a 1-time pad, but they make up for it in ease of key management. Your algorithm is a very weak stream cipher.

Comment: What if numeric constants like pi are used that are infinite, but don't just repeat a set of numbers agian and agian?

Comment: We would obviously not be using pi.

Comment: @Zeppo: Then the information content of your key is still extremely low, and it doesn't take much for the attacker to guess "Hey, that's pi!" You can use a harder-to-guess irrational number, but the harder it is to guess, the more bits you need to store it. For the key to be unguessable, it would have to take as much space to store as the message itself, and then you're back to a real one-time-pad, but with unnecessary complications.

Comment: The idea here was for two people to be able to generate matching OTP key sets without communicating after they exchange the algorithms to generate the keys.I obviously realize that using pi would be insecure, but if you read my description of the algorithm that I proposed, I took some measures to try and stop people from figuring out what constants I am using.Since there are infinitely many math constants, I could fairly easily pick an obscure one.

Comment: @Zeppo: You could pick an obscure one pretty easily, but the amount of space required to describe your key is directly proportional to the difficulty of guessing it. If your key requires a 20 KB program to generate its digits, you might as well just use a 20 KB key. If your key can be generated by a 20 byte function, your adversary only needs to guess 20 bytes.

Comment: What's the relevance of that sentence supposed to be? "after they exchange the algorithms"? The algorithms are essentially your keys; if you exchanged really complicated algorithms, you could have instead exchanged giant one-time pads. If you exchanged simple algorithms, guessing the algorithm is proportionately simple.

Answer (score 0):

Most people associate with OTP what Wikipedia terms OTP with “truly random key”. Only for this kind the strong cryptographic results do hold. Everything else is just a strange way to implement a less secure encryption scheme.

A truly random key, by its very definition, has an entropy equal to ist size. Colloquially speaking, there is no shorter way to describe the key than by printing it out. A repeating decimal which comes from the fraction of two moderately sized integers has a shorter description, and therefore less entropy. Since the main oint of your considerations appears to be finding a shorter description, it is bound to fail.